# How can I get device phone number in Appcelerator Titanium?

Tags: titanium, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium, appcelerator-mobile, sim-card

Recently I found that in Cordova it is possible to obtain user's phone number ([cordova plugin link](https://github.com/pbakondy/cordova-plugin-sim)).If Cordova can do that, than Appcelerator should too.

How can I do that in Appcelerator Titanium?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made a module a while ago and uploaded it to github: https://github.com/m1ga/com.miga.gsm

- Version 1.0: Ti 5.x
- Version 2.0: Ti 6.x

this will get you some of the fields the cordova plugin gives you. It will read the phone number but as mentioned in the page you've posted it's not reliable.

Comment: to add to it, it is impossible on iOS

Comment: @RenePot: So how is it possible with cordova plugin?

Comment: it's only showing `{ "carrierName": "",  "countryCode": "",  "mcc": "",  "mnc": "",  "allowsVOIP": false}` on iOS as far as I understood the readme

Comment: @miga: Thank you very much for help and a module.